# iOS: Twitter Paging adding more Tweets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, twitter

I am attempting to add Pagination to my Twitter Client on iOS using AFNetworking. However when I run the method to get the tweets I get this error:

```
2015-02-01 15:39:47.428 Floadt[49165:2116574] CRASH :
 -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
2015-02-01 15:39:47.429 Floadt[49165:2116574] STACK TRACE :
 (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101f2f35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010fe8bbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101f2e6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001101eb6ea -[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:] + 106
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110117a43 -[NSMutableArray insertObjects:count:atIndex:] + 179
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110117774 -[NSMutableArray insertObjectsFromArray:range:atIndex:] + 372
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110117574 -[NSMutableArray addObjectsFromArray:] + 612
    7   Floadt                              0x000000010cadc9ac __57-[TwitterTableViewController fetchNextTwitterPageWithID:]_block_invoke + 188
    8   Floadt                              0x000000010cabdcc3 __64-[AFJSONRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:]_block_invoke91 + 51
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011234cba6 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011236a7f4 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001123538fb _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 949
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011015afe9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011011deeb __CFRunLoopRun + 2043
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x000000011011d486 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
    15  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000111b7a9f0 GSEventRunModal + 161
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ebd3420 UIApplicationMain + 1282
    17  Floadt                              0x000000010cb30ed3 main + 115
    18  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000011239f145 start + 1
    19  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
```

Here is my method to get the older tweets:

```
-(void)fetchNextTwitterPageWithID:(NSString *)objectID {
    self.twitterClient = [[AFOAuth1Client alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/"] key:@"XXXXXX" secret:@"XXXXXX"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{
                                 @"max_id" :objectID
                                 };

    AFOAuth1Token *twitterToken = [AFOAuth1Token retrieveCredentialWithIdentifier:@"TwitterToken"];
    [self.twitterClient setAccessToken:twitterToken];
    [self.twitterClient registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self.twitterClient getPath:@"statuses/home_timeline.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSMutableArray *responseArray = (NSMutableArray *)responseObject;
        //NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);
        tweets = [tweets copy];
        [tweets addObjectsFromArray:responseArray];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];
}
```

Here is my method to detect that the User reached the bottom of the table view (this works perfectly fine):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([tweets count] == (indexPath.row+1)) {
        NSDictionary *totalArray = tweets[indexPath.row];
        NSString *cellID = [totalArray objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"%@",cellID);
        [self fetchNextTwitterPageWithID:cellID];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Is your "tweets" array mutable? Your error says that you use some method of NSMutableArray on not mutable array. addObjectsFromArray is one of them for example. 
Check your NSArrays and what you do with them. Maybe you insert/replace/add objects to it.